# php: click the submit button but it dosen't work

Tags: php, html, forms

This website say I can't put too many code. So I put these pictures for intance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```java
<form name="form1" method="post" action='doAction.php?option=add&a=<?php echo $_GET["id"]?"update&id=".$_GET["id"]:"add";?>'>
                        <table width="820px" height="500px" border="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="500px" align="center" style="font-size:20px;line-height: 100px"><div>公告主题：</div></td>
                                <td width="500px" height="50px">
                                    <input name="title" type="text" id="txt_title" size="40"
                                           style="width: 500px; height: 50px"
                                           value="<?php
                                    $result = null;
                                    if ($id = $_GET['id']) {
                                        //1.导入配置文件和Model类
                                        require("config.php");
                                        require("Model.php");
                                        $mod = new Model('tb_notice');                     //实例化类
                                        $result = $mod->find($id);                         //调用find()方法
                                        echo $result['title'];                         //读取标题字段
                                    }?>">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="500px" align="center" style="font-size: 20px">公告内容：</td>
                                <td><textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="40" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;margin: 0px;"
                                              id="txt_content" value="<?php echo $result['content']?>"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="40" colspan="2" align="center">
                                    <input  type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="修改/添加">
                                    &nbsp;<input type="reset" name="Submit2" id="Submit2" value="重置"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

**when I clicked the submit button, it didn't work. But when I clicked the reset button , it works.**

**Here is a animation.** 
[image]
[image]

**Do I need to submit any other information?**

===update===

when I changed:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="doAction.php?option=add&a=<?php if ($_GET['id']) {
    echo "update&id=$_GET[id]";
    } else {
        echo "add";
    } ?>">
```

**TO:**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="doAction.php?option=add&a=add">
```

It works.

Why?
[image]

Comment: you have to make sure the action on the form. Check for the same. if still not works, try button tag instead of the input type submit

Comment: and also check the validation on the input fields.

Comment: I have updated the question.Could you take a look again for me?@BirendraSingh

Comment: Check the actual HTML output your PHP is creating …

Comment: console output:
```
[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your this section

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action='doAction.php?option=add&a=<?php echo $_GET["id"]?"update&id=".$_GET["id"]:"add";?>'>
```

with

```
<?php
    $str = "add"; 
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'])
    {
        $str = "update&id=".$_GET['id'];
    }
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="doAction.php?option=add&a=<?php echo $str ; ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you!@Majid Ahmadi

Answer (score 0):

check form alonely becouse your form alonely worked
maybe prevent to submit in another section of page with javascript

Comment: I have updated the question.Can you take a look again for me?@Majid Ahmadi

Comment: send all of content in your document , becouse your form alonely worked in both times

Comment: I have uploaded it as  pictures.@Majid Ahmadi